# Onchange of a checkbox call a function , get return values and then submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have checkbox which onchange calls a function and does some operations. At the end of the function I get 2 values. I need to send these values to the server onsubmitting the form. How can i do this??

**myjsp**

```
<script>
function fnsimplecalc(){
//some calculations...
var w1=/*some value*/;
var w2=/*some value*/;
}
</script>
    <form name="test" id= "testid" action="Controller" method="post" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkid" onchange="fnsimplecalc()">
    </form>
```

I need to submit the form to the server after i get the values from the fnsimplecalc() function. How do I do this?

Comment: search for "jquery post"

Comment: Add what you have tried.

Comment: I have added what i have done. Not knowing how to pass values .

Comment: which some values are you talking about? And how do you want to submit the form? Via ajax or via default form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two hidden fields inside the form that get populated by your function.

```
<form name="test" id= "testid" action="Controller" method="post" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkid" onchange="fnsimplecalc()">
    <input type="hidden" id="x" value="">
    <input type="hidden id="y" value="">
</form>
```

Then your function should populate this fields

```
function fnsimplecalc(){
    //some calculations...
    var w1=/*some value*/;
    var w2=/*some value*/;

    $('#x').val(w1);
    $('#y').val(w2);
 }
```

When you submit your form, the hidden fields will be submitted as well.